# org.springframework.mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I got a scenario where i need to map one object to another object (POJOs) based on properties fields.

I googled and came to know i can do that using
1. BeanUtils
2. BeanWrapper
3. Spring 3 Object Mapping

i was looking for option 3 http://static.springsource.org/spring/previews/mapping.html

It uses  org.springframework.mapping.support package:

can anyone help me to get jar for the same ?

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: this is not a real question, use maven if you want to get all the dependencies properly

Comment: maven can't resolve this dependency, and even if you try to search for it, you'll find it doesnt appear to exist, besides being mentioned on that spring preview page. odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use Dozer. It's very powerful and simple to use.

> Dozer is a Java Bean to Java Bean mapper that recursively copies data from one object to another.

[Dozer home](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this never made it into the library, see this JIRA:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6137